# Counting measure and powerset

Tags: measure-theory

I am considering the counting measure $\tau$ on $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{X}))$. I am considering the paving of all $\tau$-nullsets given by:

$\mathbb{N}_{\tau}= \left\{ N \subseteq \mathcal{X} : \exists E \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{X}) \hspace{0,1cm} \text{such that } N \subseteq E \hspace{0,1cm} \text{and }\tau(E)=0   \right\}$.

I wish to show that:

a) $\mathbb{N}_{\tau}= \left\{ \emptyset \right\}$

b) $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{X})_{\tau}=\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{X})$

**My thoughts**

If $A \subseteq \mathcal{X}$ and $\tau(A)=0$ then $A=\emptyset$ and therefore $\mathbb{N}_{\tau}$ consists of subsets of nullsets, i.e. of $\emptyset$. Therefore $\mathbb{N}_{\tau}=\left\{ \emptyset \right\}$.

b) I do not understand the question so clarification and hints would be appreciated.

Comment: For b, I am just a little confused about the notation. Is $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{X})_{\tau}$ the sigma algebra of $\tau$-measurable sets?

Comment: For a) Is my reasoning correct? For b) This what I think!